# Change the appearance of badge value in UITabBarController iOS?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uibaritem

How can I change the text font and the location of a badge value in a UITabBarController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this class. You can give custom appearance to the badge using this class

https://github.com/enryold/UITabBarItem-CustomBadge/